# Efficient way to translate a camera dolly

Tags: three.js, webvr

I currently have a VR camera attached to a dolly in order to allow for translation and rotation.
I'm trying to translate the dolly, based on gamepad inputs, relative to the orientation of the camera (which is linked to a VR headset.)

I'm also trying to avoid letting the dolly pitch up or down relative to the camera.

My current code looks something like this:

```
this.camerDirectionVector = new THREE.Vector3()
this.camera.getWorldDirection(this.cameraDirectionVector)
this.moveVec.y = 0
this.dolly.translateOnAxis(this.cameraDirectionVector, this.gamepad.axes[0] * this.moveSpeed)
```

This works great for moving the dolly in the direction the camera is pointing (minus y rotation).

What I can't figure out is how to also translate the dolly "left and right" relative to the camera based off an additional gamepad input.

Comment: The way I'm reading this is that your to VR user is tied to a dolly, and you want to control the dolly's transformations in specific ways by means of a controller. Like riding on a real dolly with casters. Is that a good summary/analogy?

Comment: Yes. To my knowledge, when using Three's Vr rendering, you cannot translate the camera directly. I've attached the camera then to a dolly, and would like to be able to rotate the dolly, and translate it, relative to the current orientation of the camera, using gamepad inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that ended up working best for me. I've adapted it from Brian Peiris code here: https://github.com/brianpeiris/three-firstperson-vr-controls/blob/master/FirstPersonVRControls.js#L125

```
// Create a dolly
this.dolly = new THREE.Group()
this.dolly.add(this.camera)
this.scene.add(this.dolly)

// Some variables for movement translations
this.dummy = new THREE.Object3D()
this.dummyDirection = new THREE.Vector3()
this.ZAXIS = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)
this.moveSpeed = 0.075

// Get controller stick positions
const stickForwardBack = this.leftStick[3]
const stickLeftRight = this.leftStick[2]

// In THREE.js when using the WebXR API, the camera rotation will not update to match the headset orientation.
// You'll need to get pose information from the XRSession or get the xr camera using the following method.
const xrCamera = globals.renderer.xr.getCamera(this.camera)
this.dummy.position.set(0, 0, 0)
this.dummy.quaternion.copy(xrCamera.quaternion)
this.collapseY(this.dummy.quaternion)

// Translate the dummy object forwards/backwards left/right relative to the direction the camera is facing
this.dummy.translateZ(stickForwardBack * this.moveSpeed)
this.dummy.translateX(stickLeftRight * this.moveSpeed)

// Add the dummy position to the dolly
this.dolly.position.add(this.dummy.position)

// Flatten out up and down rotation
collapseY(quaternion) {
    this.dummyDirection.set(0, 0, 1)
    this.dummyDirection.applyQuaternion(quaternion)
    this.dummyDirection.y = 0
    this.dummyDirection.normalize()
    quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(this.ZAXIS, this.dummyDirection)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on the question, I think I understand. If I don't, please leave a comment, and I'll update this answer.

My understanding is that you want to be able to move left and right, with respect to the *camera*, all without altering the dolly's `up` direction.

This is actually easier than it sounds, and is even easier because you are already comfortable translating along an axis.

First, understand that the camera has its own spatial frame of reference, where it sits at the origin, with a +Y `up` direction, and it looks down the -Z axis. With this in mind, you already know the "left" and "right" axes: -X (`-1, 0, 0`) and +X (`1, 0, 0`).

But the camera (especially in VR) might not be so nicely aligned in world space, so you need to convert these nice uniform axes into world axes. Three.js makes this very easy using `Object3D.localToWorld`.

(*Note: `Object3D.localToWorld` is destructive to the input `Vector3`.*)

Here's a function to get the world-aligned left axis:

```
const getLeftWorld = (function(){

  const localLeft = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

  return function(vectorRef){ // you can give it a vector to overwrite
    let out = vectorRef || new THREE.Vector3();
    out.copy(localLeft);
    camera.localToWorld(out);
    return out;
  };

))();
```

You can create a similar function for the "right" axis.

With your new world-aligned left axis in hand, you can translate the dolly along it, using the "speed" given by your controller input. Translation won't change the pitch of the dolly, though it *may* change the elevation, depending on how the camera is tipped at the time of computation (but you can just zero-out the `y` component like you did before, if you want).

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this approach. I'm using a more imperative style for a demonstration (comments aren't kind to code here): https://gist.github.com/briancw/c95464187b33e385da12edc0d5596a15
I'm getting this as a result:
https://youtu.be/u7WvlzFkPMM

Comment: @BrianWhicheloe That's strange. Even if the Y and Z axes were swapped, I've never seen a system where X is vertical. I'd almost recommend doing a programmatic version where the dolly simply moves in a circle without input, just to see if you can get it to move in a planar orientation along the "ground."